# How to distinguish gibberish from legitimate expressions in formal languanges?

Tags: logic, reference-request, formal-languages

I'm reading Johnstone's *Notes on Logic and Set Theory.*

> [image]

And here he shows that there is a very simple algorithm to distinguish *gibberish* $(M\setminus F_\Omega(X))$ from legitimate expressions $(F_\Omega (X))$:

> [image]

I thought this to be extremely clever due to the simplicity of the algorithm and I think, perhaps there is a general theory about this distinction that can be applied to programming languages and other formal languages. Is there such a thing or this algorithm can (somehow) be applied to all such decision problems?

Comment: This topic is the topic of parsing formal languages and is a very standard part of computer science education. There are tons of resources, many freely available, on this topic. While I don't recommend it for you currently (but I do recommend returning to it in the future), [here's](https://doi.org/10.1016/0743-1066(95)00035-I) an approach of thinking about parsing algorithms in terms of deductive systems. To be clear, the simplicity of the algorithm in this case is partly due to using a simple but not particularly human-friendly syntax. memmixyiz is not as clear as m(e,m(m(i(x),y),i(z))).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the language here is context free, and the described algorithm is basically a push-down automaton (the counter is represented by the automaton's stack). For more information about various classes of formal languages, and algorithms for their recognition, I recommend [Michael Sipser's book.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/113318779X)